# How do I avoid ambiguous naming between my PHP-code and an SQL junction table?

Tags: php, sql, naming-conventions

Given the following database schema (MySQL), I'm worried about possibly introducing ambiguous naming in its PHP 5.5 model class given below (abstracted for simplicity).

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catalog_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `catalog_item_property` (
  `catalog_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `catalog_item_properties_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`catalog_item_id`,`catalog_item_properties_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `catalog_item_properties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `catalog_item_properties_description` (
  `catalog_item_properties_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`catalog_item_properties_id`,`language_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Some background on the schema:

- `catalog_item` holds items from a catalog.
- `catalog_item_property` holds all properties belonging to a `catalog_item`.
- `catalog_item_properties` holds a list of all possible item properties.
- `catalog_item_properties_description` holds a multi-language description for all `catalog_item_properties`.
- I'm following a singular naming convention for all my tables.

The interface function names that I am unsure of:

```
public function getItemProperty($id)
{
    // Get all catalog item properties that belong to this catalog item?
}

public function getItemProperties()
{
    // Get list of all possible catalog item properties?
}
```

As you can see, on my current iteration, `getItemProperty` may return more than one property. But so does `getItemProperties`. Ideally, I would like the function naming to speak for themselves, and for there to be no ambiguity at all. I would also like there to be a strong relation between the function names and the schema table names, for the sake of consistency.

Some questions I would love to hear some informed opinions on:

- Do I change either the table names, or the function names (or both?) to resolve this potential ambiguity? Or, might there be no ambiguity at all?
- Is it ok to mix the singular and plural form on table names in this scenario?

I'm pretty new to database design. If I completely missed the best practice approach here, please do let me know. Thank you in advance for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Without seeing the full (actual) table definitions, and maybe some data, it might be hard to give you a full answer.  Use whatever naming convention seems reasonable to you.  Typically a junction table's name will include the names from the two tables in between which it sits.

Comment: This probably belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), SO is only for code related issues, not review - this question is too primary opinion based.

Comment: `<opinion>`Your table names are already too verbose`</opinion>`.